# How to get the aspect ratio of an image?

Tags: arithmetic

I have an image that is:

```
320 original width
407 original height
```

I want to let users resize the image via a form I am building on a webpage. They can adjust either the width or height. When they do the other dimension should auto adjust to maintain the aspect ratio.

When a user updates the width field I get the adjusted height like so:

```
aspect ratio = original width ÷ original height
adjusted height = <user chosen width> ÷ aspect ratio
```

Is this correct?

Also how to get the adjusted width when the user changes the height field? I know it should be simple enough but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, this is correct – though it unnecessarily uses two divisions instead of one division and a multiplication, `adjusted height = <user-chosen width> * original height / original width`.

The corresponding formula for the adjusted width is `adjusted width = <user-chosen height> * original width / original height`, or if you want to do it your way, `adjusted width = <user-chosen height> * aspect ratio`, with `aspect ratio` calculated as before.

Comment: perfect, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @joriki Really Helpful.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. You said you want the aspect ratio of the adjusted image to be the same as the aspect ratio of the original equation, so you want

$\frac{\text{adjusted width}}{\text{adjusted height}} = \frac{\text{original width}}{\text{original height}}$

Multiplying both sides of the equation by the adjusted height, you get

$\text{adjusted width} = \frac{\text{original width}}{\text{original height}} \cdot \text{adjusted height}$

Then, dividing both sides of the equation by $\frac{\text{original width}}{\text{original height}}$, you get

$\text{adjusted width } / \frac{\text{original width}}{\text{original height}} = \text{adjusted height},$

which is the formula you suggested!

---

So, how do you get the adjusted width when the user adjusts the height field? The answer is hidden in the reasoning above! Can you find it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is the formula:
Aspect Ratio = Width / Height
for example:

- Width = 300

  ### - Height = 150
- Aspect Ratio = 2/1 (or 2:1)

if we want to calculate new object size, you need to have a new object dimension like height, or width to calculate remaining one preserving aspect ratio. 
let's say we have:

- New Height = 300

  ### - Aspect Ratio = 2/1
- New Width = ?
  Knowing that, or fractions should look like that:
  300 / New Width = 2 / 1  =>  New Width = 150
  Or you can calculate your new measurements [using this online aspect ratio calculator](http://www.ninjaunits.com/aspect-ratio-calculator/) that do the job for you and can calculate: aspect ratio, number of pixels (if is image) and new dimensions for objects or images keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: The url to the online calculator has changed to: https://www.ninjaunits.com/calculators/aspect-ratio/

Comment: I might be being daft, but if the original aspect ratio was 2/1, and the height is adjusted to 300 (from 150), then it seems to me that the width should be adjusted to 600, not 150, in order to maintain width/height = 2/1, I don't understand why you're adjusting to 150 here.

Answer (score 0):

> Given:

- Original Height (h0) = 400.
- Original Width (w0) = 300.
- User enters New Height (h1) as 200.

**Calculate new Width (w1).**
aspect ratio = 400/300 = 1.3333
Therefore new width = 200 / 1.3333 = 150

Another way of looking at it is, aspect ratio =4:3. So (200/4)*3 = 150